# Gluu redirect after registration

Tags: oauth, single-sign-on, openid, gluu

I have just started working with Gluu, and mostly it is working exactly as I want it to.
However I am experiencing some difficulties with registration.
Currently when a user registeres he/she is redirected to the gluu page. What I would like to happen is the user being redirected back to the page that sent the user to the registration page(or at the very least a static page).

I know that this needs to be done in the postRegistration part och the user registration script, however I am not quite sure about what it is that I need to do.

So has anyone done something like this before?

**Edit:**

So this is where I am currently at...
The postRegistration function takes in 4 parameters, self, user, requestParameters and configurationAttributes.

*self* I assume is just a reference to itself and therefore it is not really valuable in this case as there are no set functions that redirects in that class and it does not seem to hold any valuable parameters.

*user* is the user that is about to be registered and is sent down from `org.gluu.oxtrust.action.RegisterPersonAction` and is a `org.gluu.oxtrust.model.GluuCustomPerson` Object.
I believe that this is my best bet at fixing this problem... although I am not sure about how.
It does have a function `setSourceServerName` that seemed promising, but setting it did not change the outcome in any way.

*requestParameters* is just the query parameters sent in the URL. I tried setting these to valid openid code authentication parameters, but it had no effect.

*configurationAttributes* is simply the static parameters sent into the script from Gluu (just parameters set statically to the script)

Moreover the function must return a boolean so I assume that what needs to be done is changing the input parameters as a side effect and thus my only two options are the user object and requestParameters. requestParameters seems to be just a private map object in the registerPersonAction class, which does not seem to do anything special with it, so changing this shouldn't have the outcome that I want.
Therefore it must be the user object that I need to modify. However as previously stated, I do not yet know in what way

Answer (score 0):

As a dirty hack you can edit the gluu pages to insert javascript that redirects the user